# A connect wall where everybody wants to belong

Tags: word-property, connect-wall

A connect wall is usually a set of 16 words which can be split into four groups of four related words. Each of those groups can be described under a single overarching group as well. Unfortunately, that leaves the words feeling very segregated. They've gotten tired of being separated into groups, and they have formed a new group where they can all belong.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IRAQ | GNAT | SYNC | VEND |
| PHO | SENT | TRY | TANG |
| BALK | FLAP | SHE | CUB |
| FRAG | GEL | ONYX | FUR |

All 16 of these words are related in one unique way. Can you find the single tie that binds them all together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the tie is

> every word in the grid rot 13s to another one in the grid.  Like sync and flap.

Comment: I don't think that's something that ties sixteen words together. It ties two together. Something that ties sixteen words together is that they each rot13(ebg guvegrra gb fbzr inyvq jbeq).

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I saw but I couldn't find any in the grid that only did that. They seem to all require it to be a valid word IN the grid. There could be another additional special property though. Not sure.

Comment: This was the answer I had in mind